# Writing a flow to add email with only the email attachment into sharepoint (when a new email arrives)

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, office365, power-automate

[image]

I have included in a condition rule to check for every attachments that the attachment name contains RE: which is included in the name of th outlook attachment. I have also tried the condition of file does not start with image00 and end with .png to exclude picture attachments but it still does not catch the attachment that i want which is the email attachment to be included in the new file when i create a new file.

[image]

I expect a new file created containing the converted pdf version of the  body of the incoming email and the email attachment that comes with it in a single newly created file in sharepoint. I have tried using the condition rule to make sure that only the email attachment is included but in the end none of the emails pass the boolean condition and no file gets created in the end